# Give Japanese names for the badges?

Tags: discussion, badges

Could the names of badges be made Japanese? For example, student could be gakusei, and teacher could be sensei.

Badges are meant to be an optional [incentive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work), rather than something serious like reputation:

> The badges a user has earned don't have any effect on the site, they
>   are simply a sign of accomplishment and bragging rights. The user's
>   abilities are governed not by badges, but by reputation.

and giving it a different name on this Stack Exchange would provide more incentive by making it less generic and more special and unique.

Comment: I prefer kanji (using romaji is not entirely Japanese), but I understand that romaji might be a good compromise between the feeling of Japanese and the easiness for beginners.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: Maybe romaji for bronze, kana for silver, kanji for gold?

Comment: Maybe, although I do not think that badge colors correspond well to the maturity of the user in the subject.

Comment: +1 just thought it's pretty cool idea =D